# How to solve Admin socket not configured in ofbiz

Tags: java, eclipse, ant, ofbiz

I am new in Apache ofbiz.i have downloaded and configured it with ant.Its running locally now in my machine.

```
"https://localhost:8443/catalog/control/main" its my local URL.
```

Now i am trying to configure with eclipse.But after importing this to eclipse i have done run Ant in build Xml.Then i have gone to debug configuration,i right click on java remote application new ofbiz,now the parametrs are connection type-->Standered(socket attach),
Host-->localhost,port-->8443.But when i am clicking on the debug button,its showing the error.I am getting this error.

```
Start.java using configuration file org/ofbiz/base/start/start.properties 
Set OFBIZ_HOME to - C:/apache-ofbiz-11.04.04 
Admin socket not configured; set to port 0 
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ExceptionInInitializerError 
at org.ofbiz.base.util.Debug.<clinit>(Debug.java:86) 
at org.ofbiz.base.container.ContainerLoader.load(ContainerLoader.java:78) 
at org.ofbiz.base.start.Start.initStartLoaders(Start.java:169) 
at org.ofbiz.base.start.Start.init(Start.java:139) 
at org.ofbiz.base.start.Start.main(Start.java:69) 
Caused by: java.util.MissingResourceException: Can't find bundle for base name cache,   locale en 
at java.util.ResourceBundle.throwMissingResourceException(Unknown Source) 
at java.util.ResourceBundle.getBundleImpl(Unknown Source) 
at java.util.ResourceBundle.getBundle(Unknown Source) 
at org.ofbiz.base.util.cache.UtilCache.setPropertiesParams(UtilCache.java:212) 
at org.ofbiz.base.util.cache.UtilCache.setPropertiesParams(UtilCache.java:208) 
at org.ofbiz.base.util.cache.UtilCache.<init>(UtilCache.java:138) 
at org.ofbiz.base.util.cache.UtilCache.createUtilCache(UtilCache.java:1015) 
 at org.ofbiz.base.util.UtilProperties.<clinit>(UtilProperties.java:71) 
... 5 more
```

Comment: why admin socket not configured msg is showing???plase help

Answer (score 1):

remote debug not using your HTTP port, need using JPDA port
add parameter to your command -Xrunjdwp:transport=dt_socket,server=y,suspend=n,address=8091 -jar ofbiz.jar
see https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/OFBIZ/Running+and+Debugging+OFBiz+in+Eclipse

Comment: where i should put this line

Comment: how you start you ofbiz, I think you can put it on you ant file somewhere. the start command in your ant file

Comment: there is a startofbiz file in the ofbiz source i use to open this file and then hit the localhost..i am trying to merge it with eclipse

Comment: do you see DEBUG option in startofbiz file, try to un-comment it.

Comment: I know that, remove the REM of line: rem "%JAVA_HOME%\bin\java" -Xms128M -Xmx512M -XX:MaxPermSize=512m -Xdebug -Xnoagent -Djava.compiler=NONE -Xrunjdwp:transport=dt_socket,server=y,suspend=n,address=5005 -jar ofbiz.jar > runtime\logs\console.log add rem of line: 
"%JAVA_HOME%\bin\java" -Xms128M -Xmx512M -XX:MaxPermSize=512m -jar ofbiz.jar

Comment: Admin socket not configured; set to port 0

Comment: Caused by: java.util.MissingResourceException: Can't find bundle for base name cache, locale en
 at java.util.ResourceBundle.throwMissingResourceException(Unknown Source)
 at java.util.ResourceBundle.getBundleImpl(Unknown Source)
 at java.util.ResourceBundle.getBundle(Unknown Source)
 at org.ofbiz.base.util.cache.UtilCache.setPropertiesParams(UtilCache.java:212)
 at org.ofbiz.base.util.cache.UtilCache.setPropertiesParams(UtilCache.java:208)
 at org.ofbiz.base.util.cache.UtilCache.<init>(UtilCache.java:138)
 at org.ofbiz.base.util.cache.UtilCache.createUtilCache(UtilCache.java:1015)

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/53898/discussion-between-andy-and-lucifer)

Comment: plese see my bat file i have posted it in the chat

Answer (score 0):

This happens due to classpath settings in your ‘run configuration’:
 - I resolved this  error  by removing the entry ‘ofbiz(default classpath)’ for 'User Entries' in ‘classpath’ tab in ‘run configuration’ for ofbiz, and replacing it with ofbiz.jar. 
In other words :

- Go to 'classpath' tab in 'run configuration' for ofbiz.
- Remove existing 'ofbiz(default classpath)' entry in 'User Entries' and replace it with 'ofbiz.jar' from your ofbiz folder.